# Permissions to edit content type not working

Tags: users

I am wondering if I have missed some place obvious. I have permissions set for the role "editor" to be able to edit several content types. It is working for all but one of these types. We are also using organic groups. I have confirmed that these nodes are set to the correct group, the editor is in that group. They can see the content, but can't edit. Is there some other hidden place where there might be a permission set that I'm not seeing?

We have D7, the path where we are editing permissions is /admin/people/permissions
and organic groups is the only "content access" on this installation.

Comment: Consider editing your question to explain (a) which admin URL you used to set those permissions and (b) if you use any kind of access modules and (c) if this is D6 or D7 ...

Comment: as well as if its a distribution (kickstart, etc) - they sometimes override permission or use custom permissions modules to handle certain conditions